# enable excel workbooks when userform is open

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a workbook that opens a user-form when the workbook is opened. This has caused a problem because it then disables all open excel workbooks so users cant make changes to other workbooks

Is there a way i can let users still edit/open other open workbooks and still keep the user-form open?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to open user form with `Modal` parameter set to `vbModeless`:

```
Call UserForm.Show(vbModeless)
```

Comment: If i select a different work book then try the change one of the comboboxes in my userform i get an error message as the workbook linked to the userform is not selected. How would i select the workbook if the userform is active? @mielk

Comment: @PeterMogford Probably you already found answer. But you can avoid this by changing `ShowModal` to `False` in that userform properties instead of writing through code

Answer (score 8):

On the properties of the user form change `ShowModal` to false.